# Redmine Updating Images

Tags: ckeditor, redmine, ckfinder

Our Redmine server has CKEditor, which allows for inserting images into Wiki pages, documents, etc.

The images are embedded into the pages via a direct link to the image, i.e. `https://redmineserver/attachments/download/94/someimage.png`.

The only way we know of to update this image is to delete it then upload the new image. The problem is that the new image will be at a different directory, i.e. `https://redmineserver/attachments/download/89/someimage.png`, thus breaking all our previous links to `https://redmineserver/attachments/download/94/someimage.png`.

There is an extension called CKFinder which will fixes this, but we're looking for a free alternative (without coding our own plugin).

Does anybody know of another plugin to update images without breaking their references?

Comment: CKFinder is really good and not really that expensibe to be honest. There is one called KCFinder, but I think it might be PHP only *sadface*. Why would the images be at a different directory though? If it something your upload thing enforces, can't you bypass it and upload via FTP or something? Or just rewrite the uploader and keep using whatever you use now to pick the image.

Comment: It's just the way Redmine is; the only way to update an image is to delete the image and upload the new version. Uploading the new version puts that new image in a different directory.